# Convert main args to span<std::string_view> without ranges

Tags: c++, c++17

This question has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62218832/498437) by using ranges, but I'm using C++17 with a backport of `std::span` - so I have spans but not ranges.

Consider this simple function:

```
std::span<std::string_view> cmdline_args_to_span(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    return std::span<const char*>(argv, argc);
}
```

I *thought* the converting constructor of `span` would kick in due to the `const char*` constructor of `std::string_view` but it isn't.  And neither is:

```
std::span<std::string_view> cmdline_args_to_span(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    auto c_args = std::span<const char*>(argv, argc);
    return std::span<std::string_view>(c_args);
}
```

Or:

```
std::span<std::string_view> cmdline_args_to_span(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    auto c_args = std::span<const char*>(argv, argc);
    return std::span<std::string_view>(c_args.begin(), c_args.end());
}
```

[All of these fail](https://godbolt.org/z/6qs9x6vxv) on both Clang and gcc (using the 'real' `std::span` but it's the same for my backported version).

I must be doing something stupid, but I can't see what - can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Convert main args to `spanstd::string_view without ranges
>
> This question has been answered before

You'll notice that the "answered before" solution doesn't create a `std::span<std::string_view>` at all.

`std::span` is not an adapter range whose iterators would generate objects upon indirection such as `std::views::transform` is and does. You cannot have a `std::span<std::string_view>` unless you have an array of `std::string_view` objects. And those objects won't be stored within the span.

`std::span<std::string_view>` isn't very convenient for command line arguments. But, you could first create a `std::vector<std::string_view>` and then a span pointing to the vector. Since command line arguments are global, this is a rare case where a static storage doesn't suffer from significant problems - unless the caller mistakenly thinks that they can call it with varying arguments:

```
std::span<std::string_view>
cmdline_args_to_span(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    static std::vector<std::string_view> args(argv, argv + argc);
    return args;
}
```

> but I'm using C++17 with a backport of std::span - so I have spans but not ranges.

Ranges can be had pre-C++20 even though the standard library doesn't have them. In fact, the standard ranges are based on a library that works in C++14.

That said, in case you aren't interested in using any of the pre-existing range libraries, then implementing a transform view yourself involves quite a bit of boilerplate.

Comment: Why don't you just return the `vector` instead?

Comment: @PasserBy Then you wouldn't have a `std::span` that was asked for :)

Comment: I'm kicking myself, you're absolutely right.  _Obviously_ a span can't transform the element types as it doesn't own the underlying storage, I'd need a transforming view which I need the ranges library for.  The vector idea I can't use as the primary motivation for using a span was to avoid an allocation (good idea though!), so I guess I'll have to fall back to `span<const char*>`.